# Reusing a pointer of double array without memory leak in C++ via "delete" crashes the program

Tags: c++, pointers

I've tried the (somewhat questionable) convention of `delete`ing after usage, but that doesn't seem to work. The program is supposed to receive an input of a single integer, sort a randomly created array, and print elapsed time for sorting, yet when I leave the `delete` in there, the program abnormally ends without even a warning after I do the input. In other words, it crashes. However, when I comment out just the `delete` line, the program executes perfectly.

The MWE is measuring time for a simple Quick Sort Algorithm, and since this is a school project I cannot change the `main()` function and using the `QuickSort` class and its pointers, etc..

The only things I can change are the stuff that goes in the various functions, and although it does seem that `set(double*, int)` can just be integrated into the constructor, that's not a possible option here for some reason.

The objective is to define a default `double*` in the constructor, and then delete it and copy `input_array` into `this->arr` in `set`:

EDIT: I use Windows 10 and the GCC C++ Compiler from MinGw-w64. All compilations have been executed in the Windows Command Prompt.

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // Just for good measure, though this shouldn't be needed
#include "Sort.hpp"

bool check_quick(QuickSort *quick_sort) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < (quick_sort->size) - 1) {
        if (quick_sort->arr[i] > quick_sort->arr[i + 1]) break;
        ++i;
    } if (i == (quick_sort->size) - 1) return true;
    else return false;
}

int main() {
    int n; cin >> n;
    double *input_array = new double[n];
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) input_array[k] = (double)((rand() % n));

    QuickSort* quick_sort = new QuickSort();
    quick_sort->set(input_array, n);
    quick_sort->run();
    if (check_quick(quick_sort)) {
        cout << "QuickSort is validated" << endl << endl;
    } delete quick_sort;
}
```

`Sort.hpp`

```cpp
#define CLOCKS_PER_SECOND 1000
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip> // Use to call setprecision(4)
using namespace std;

class QuickSort {
    friend bool check_quick(QuickSort*); // Give access for private variables
public:
    void print_time() const {
        cout << "QuickSort : " << fixed << setprecision(4) << seconds
             << " sec" << endl;
        // << fixed << setprecision(4) always prints to four numbers after point
    }
    QuickSort() {
        this->arr = new double[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) this->arr[i - 1] = i; // Set default array
        seconds = clock(); // Set current Millisecond to starting time
    }
    ~QuickSort() {
        delete this->arr; // Delete array in object of this class
    }
    void sorter(double *arr, int begin, int end) { // Sorting Recursive Function
        // Size of array without pivot is: end - begin
        int pivot = arr[end];
            // PIVOT is element at end of subarray "arr[begin...end]"
        int i = begin, j = end;
        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot) i++; // Increment until arr[i] is larger than
            while (arr[j] > pivot) j--; // Decrement until arr[j] is lesser than
            if (i <= j) { // If the larger element precedes lesser element
                swap(arr[i], arr[j]); // Call Swap function
                i++; j--;
            } // If i is larger than j now, i was 1 lesser than j before,
              // effectively leaving no more elements to scan.
        }
        if (begin < j) sorter(this->arr, begin, j); // Recursive, larger part
        if (end > i) sorter (this->arr, i, end); // Recursive, lesser part
    }
    void run() {
        sorter(this->arr, 0, this->size - 1); // Call Sorter function
        seconds = (double)(clock() - seconds) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SECOND);
            // Calculate Difference of Ticks and divide by Ticks per second.
            // Now, `seconds` is passed seconds with millisecond precision.
    }
    void set(double *arr, int size) {
        this->arr = new double[size]; // Make new array of `size` size
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) this->arr[i] = arr[i]; // Copy input_arr
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << this->arr[i] << endl; // Copy input_arr
        this->size = size; // Save global `size` to object of class
    }
    void swap(double &p, double &q) { // Swap Function
                                      // Ampersand precedence to change input
        double x = p; // Temporary `double` saver
        p = q; // p is q
        q = x; // q is x, which is p
    }
private:
    double *arr;
    int size;
    double seconds;
};
```

Comment: Why does `quick_sort` need to be dynamically allocated? Or a pointer at all for that matter? Also naming a parameter in a member function the same as a member variable is asking for trouble.

Comment: Side note : whenever you're no longer bound by stupid professor restrictions just use unique ptr instead of bare pointers or std vector for dynamic allocated arrays.

Comment: `QuickSort* quick_sort = new QuickSort();` You should not dynamically allocate your QuickSort object.

Comment: the convention is rather to use no `delete` at all, at least not directly

Comment: @scohe001 "bound by stupid professors..." and frankly, none of the students understand the need for it to be a pointer at all.

Comment: Modern `c++` removes the need for manual memory management.

Comment: @SombreroChicken why wait for it until it is too late? Writing your own simple version of a smart pointer is not too difficult and should be lecture number zero instead of this "you have to use raw pointers in order to learn it the hard way" non-sense

Comment: @drescherjm Would dynamic allocation create complications?

Comment: @user463035818 Hm, maybe I should change that, guess it reflects the "professor's perception of" the convention...

Comment: It makes the problem harder than it needs to be and discourages new people to the language because of the unnecessary complexity taught at the wrong time. There is a very good youtube lecture / talk on the topic. Although I don't have a link.

Comment: @user463035818 Very true, that's another good option. I'm so done with universities teaching students C instead of C++.

Comment: @drescherjm You probably mean https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk

Comment: About [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `QuickSort` constructor you are writing outside the bounds of the array that you are allocating:

```
this->arr = new double[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) this->arr[i - 1] = i; // Set default array
```

In the first iteration `i` is `0` so `this->arr[i - 1]` writes to the element `-1`. This is only crashing when you call `delete` as if you don't the runtime doesn't notice this corruption and exits cleanly.

Presumably just changing `i-1` to `i` will produce the desired behaviour.

Comment: Took me ages to find it too, just after I found it I noticed the new green squiggly line in VS 2019 which said "index of array is -1"

Answer (score 2):

The first line of `QuickSort::set`:

```
this->arr = new double[size]; // Make new array of `size` size
```

leaks the array allocated in `QuickSort`'s constructor.  You need to `delete[]` that array first, before assigning `arr` to point to another one:

```
delete[] arr;
this->arr = new double[size]; // Make new array of `size` size
```

---

If this were the real world, and not a shcool assignment, it would be much better not to use a raw pointer in this case.  Rather, a `std::vector<double>` would be much more appropriate.

Comment: I just tried this solution as well, but the program still doesn't work. There's no output produced.

Comment: You should edit your question to include more information about your problem.  This avoids the obvious memory leak, since that's what the question's title asks about.

Comment: I don't know what other details I can provide; Just commenting out the `delete[]` line does really work, as in sorting and measuring time.

Comment: @K.Paul Perhaps Eric Lippert's [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) article will be of help to you.

Comment: I'd consider this is rather a comment than an answer; a memory leak won't provoke crash of a programme – unless we leaked that much memory that OS cannot provide us with more, but I doubt pretty much we got at this point. Still a good catch.

Comment: @Aconcagua The original question didn't mention a crash.  It only mentioned a memory leak, so I answered as such.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look reveals that you are using `delete` instead of `delete[]`..

this line:

> delete this->arr; // Delete array in object of this class

should be:

> delete[] this->arr; // Delete array in object of this class

Additionally, as per the convention of delete you should also do this:

> delete[] this->arr;
>   this->arr = nullptr;  // This is important, else your are double deleting which is calling for trouble.

Comment: I tried that too, but the problem doesn't work even with that change.

Comment: @K.Paul Can you define "doesn't work"?  What exactly fails?  Do you get the wrong output?  Does it crash?

Comment: Crashes, exactly came symptoms as before: no output produced.

Comment: Works after the `this->arr = nullptr`! Thank you.

Comment: No...sorry, false alarm, I retried and it still produces the same problem.

Comment: `this->arr = nullptr` in a *destructor* is totally obsolete, as `arr` (here!) is an ordinary pointer, not a smart pointer. So there won't be any double deletion either, and the variable runs out of scope after exiting the destructor anyway.

Comment: @Aconcagua you're correct. I missed its inside a Destructor. I was talking more in terms of delete convention he was talking about.

Comment: @K.Paul, finally to save everyone's time, I tried to execute it on my box. It runs without crashes. Can you specify which OS/Compiler you are using.. And also please provide code for function `check_quick`

Comment: OK.. i do not have the environment that you are running. But I have slightly formatted the code for you so its easier to debug. Here's the code https://pastebin.com/2WL54z3F